# aspectj throwing ClassCastException

Tags: java, gradle, aspectj

I am trying to build some java 1.6 application with aspects after migrating the build from some older gradle version to gradle 6.3. Because of the newer gradle version, I am using java 9.

The aspect compiler throws ClassCastException (link to log below), which, if I understand correctly, is caused by compiler not finding java.lang.Object class. I am only guessing it might something to do with using java 9 to run the build, but targeting java 1.6 compatibility. If this is the case, how do I tell the compiler where to find it? I tried to pass the `-1.6` argument to ajc, but nothing changed.

I also include my build.gradle contents - I apologize it is not fully in gradle 6.3, because I got stuck on this aspectj compilation problem, before migrating it fully.

Thanks in advance for every response.

build.gradle contents:

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
      maven {
        url "${artifactoryURL}/libs-releases"
      }
   }
   dependencies {
      classpath "io.freefair.gradle:aspectj-plugin:5.0.0-rc6"
      classpath "gradle.plugin.org.myire:quill:2.3.1"
   }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'io.freefair.aspectj.post-compile-weaving'
apply plugin: 'org.myire.quill.cobertura'
apply from: 'https://localnet/public/gradle/trunk/repositories.gradle'

java {
   sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
}

group = "cz.svt"
version = "${version}"

aspectj {
   version = "1.6.8"
}

configurations.all {
    transitive = false
}

dependencies {
   compile('avalon:avalon:4.2.0')
   compile('cglib:cglib-nodep:2.2')
   compile('commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.7.0')
   compile('commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3')
   compile('commons-collections:commons-collections:3.1')
   compile('org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.4.1')                             
   compile('commons-digester:commons-digester:1.6')
   compile('commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.1')
   compile('commons-io:commons-io:1.3.1')
   compile('commons-lang:commons-lang:2.0')
   compile('commons-logging:commons-logging:1.0.4')
   compile('commons-net:commons-net:2.0')
   compile('commons-pool:commons-pool:1.2')
   compile('commons-validator:commons-validator:1.1.3')
   compile('com.ibm.db2:jdbc3-driver:9.5')
   compile('dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1')
   compile('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:1.5.7')
   compile('org.apache.xmlgraphics:fop:0.94')
   compile('com.google.guava:guava:13.0.1')
   compile('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:1.5.7')
   compile('cz.svt:hibernate-svt:3.6.8.Final')
   compile('com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.0.2')
   compile('joda-time:joda-time:2.1')
   compile('javax.servlet:jstl:1.0.6')
   compile('junit:junit:3.8.1')
   compile('log4j:log4j:1.2.15')
   compile('mail:mail:1.0.3')
   compile('org.springframework:spring-core:1.2.9')
   compile('org.springframework:spring-beans:1.2.9')
   compile('org.springframework:spring-mock:1.2.9')
   compile('taglibs:standard:1.0.6')
   compile('struts:struts:1.2.4')
   compile('struts:struts-el:1.2.4')
   compile('strutstest:strutstest:2.1.3-1.2-2.3')
   compile('velocity:velocity:1.4')
   compile('org.apache.ant:ant:1.7.1')
   compile('org.apache.tomcat:jsp-api:6.0.18')
   compile('org.apache.tomcat:servlet-api:6.0.18')
   compile('org.apache.tomcat:catalina:6.0.18')
   compile('org.apache.tomcat:dbcp:6.0.18')
   compile('org.easymock:easymock:3.0')
   compile('cz.svt:easymock-propeq:1.3')
   compile('org.testng:testng:5.11:jdk15')

   testCompile('org.apache.ftpserver:ftplet-api:1.0.0')
   testCompile('org.apache.ftpserver:ftpserver-core:1.0.0')
   testCompile('org.apache.mina:mina-core:2.0.0-M4')

   testRuntime('org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.1')
   testRuntime('org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.6.1')
   testRuntime('org.uncommons:reportng:1.0')
   testRuntime('asm:asm:3.0')
   testRuntime('asm:asm-tree:3.0')
   testRuntime('org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:3.2.0.Final')
   testRuntime('org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:1.0.1.Final')
   testRuntime('javax.transaction:jta:1.1')
   testRuntime('antlr:antlr:2.7.6')
   testRuntime("org.objenesis:objenesis:1.2")
   testRuntime("oro:oro:2.0.7")
}

test {
   useTestNG() {
      suites 'src/test/resources/testng.xml'
      listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter'
      listeners << 'org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter'
   }
}

task reports {
    dependsOn coberturaTestReport, javadoc
}
```

here is link to aspectj compiler output [1](https://pastebin.com/wd4Cd8i7)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might wonder why your question received no answers or comments yet. Please be advised to learn what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is and then provide one. If I can reproduce the problem, I can help you. It is kind of pointless to try and answer a question without seeing any application or aspect code. Feel free to publish the MCVE (not the full original application, of course) on GitHub.

Comment: BTW, I don't see in your Gradle script where you set the Java 6 target for the Java and/or AspectJ compiler. I also recommend you to use an up to date AspectJ version (1.9.5), then you have a Java 13 capable compiler which also works with modularised JDK versions 9+ versions. You can still configure the compiler to produce Java 6 code. I cannot say more without the MCVE, though. I am an AspectJ expert and know how to use it in Maven, but am not a Gradle guy. That's why I need the MCVE to play with.

Comment: first of all - thanks for pointing out the MCVE. java 1.6 source compatibility is right below apply plugins. according to gradle documentation, it should also mean, that target compatibility is the same. i tried fiddling around with aspectj version, but it didnt help. so i left it as it was.

Comment: I see. Was anything unclear about the term MCVE? Did you read the linked description? Please do, then edit your question accordingly, unless you enjoyed waiting for a full week without any results. No offence meant. ;-)